# Is it possible to build and release iOS applications that uses newer APIs?

Tags: ios, ios4, app-store, ios5

Let's say I want to make an iOS application that is using new notifications on iOS 5 and fallback to old notifications on iOS 4.

Is it possible to release such application on App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although its not pretty.

You can read about the solution I found (on Google): http://www.marco.org/2010/11/22/supporting-older-versions-of-ios-while-using-new-apis

I'm not sure if this will work with the new push notification APIs, however. I haven't had a chance to update my app yet.